# Rails relaciones entre odelos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

AYUDA:

Hola tengo una duda para crear un modelo, resulta que tengo una tabla de Choferes (conductores) que tienes muchos campos de datos, que van desde datos personales, fecha de alta, fecha de baja, ademas de datos como no de licencia, fecha de vencimiento, status del documento ( si esta activo, vencido o por vencer, esto en base a los dias que faltan para vencer ) asi como un campo documento_licencia ( que seria la ruta de la imagen ), pero tambien tengo otros datos sobre el seguro, mi duda es, como hago para relacionar los campos status_licencia y status_seguro a la tabla DocumentStatus, como hago para hacer la relacion en la migracion y tambien entre los modelos, puesto que se relaciona 2 veces Choferes con DocumentStatus... lo mismo me pasara con Camiones, pero son mas documentos, pense en dividir en Choferes, Choferes_licencia, choferes_seguro, pero eso agregaria mas complejidad a la hora de guardar los datos y hacer las consultas.....ESPERO HABERME EXPLICADO

Comment: Hola @Leonardo puede resultar conveniente que hagas el [tour] para enterarte acerca del funcionamiento del sitio y que vayas a la página [ask] para que tengas una guía para organizar tu pregunta de modo que sea bien acogida y de lugar a respuestas que te orienten. De momento te sugiero dividir la tabla de modo que los campos poco variables queden en una de info de choferes y la muy variable como estatus de licencias, etc., y asignación de camiones vayan a otra(s) eso te hará más fácil la vida.

Comment: La complejidad a la hora de guardar es muy aparente, buenos métodos y datos bien organizados lo hacen simple.

Comment: Hola gracias, hare entonces algunas pruebas.., la verdad es que soy nuevo.. estoy tratando de migrar un sistema de una linea de trailers que desarrolle para escritorio en PowerBuilder 12.6 y SQL Server... lo estoy intentando..primero para aprender y segundo, pues para ofrecer un nuevo producto a mi cliente